# javax.mail.Folder.getMessages() returns empty once the message it has been read by getContent

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

I need to evaluate content from an email that has been sent to a gmail account. 
The problem is when I retrieve the content and close the folder. If I try to connect, open the INBOX folder and `getMessages()` for a second time then the method return empty.
I have tried setting the `SEEN`flag to false, but it didn't work.
Is there any workaround to retrieve the entire content from the INBOX folder?

Comment: Need more detail on how you're reading the message the second time.  Are you using IMAP?  What does the [JavaMail debug output(https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: Hi, I was working with Pop connection. Then I changed to Imap configuration and the problems was solved.